# How to make a UIBlurEffect that works on IPAD 3

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I'm developing a software for iOS using an IPAD 3 (MD368TY/A) as test's hardware. I'm trying to create a blur effect on a background image but i'm getting this result:

[image]

The 'correct' should be:

[image]
(result reached using Iphone 5S simulator)

My code is:

```
import UIKit

class ProfileMgmtViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var bgImageContainerView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var userBgImg: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var userImg: UIImageView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...

    userBgImg.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: userImg.image!)

    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
    let blurView  = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurView.frame = userBgImg.bounds
    print (userBgImg.bounds)
    userBgImg.addSubview(blurView)
    ...
```

I was reading that this version of IPAD doesn't supports blur effect. Is that true? There's some way to make blur effect works here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's true, from this WWDC session: http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/419

> So, and to reiterate on what devices we don't blur and that we only do
>   the tinting on the iPad 2 and iPad 3rd generation, we just apply the
>   tint and we skip the blur steps.
>
> On iPad 4th generation, iPad Air, iPad Mini, iPad Mini with retina
>   display, iPhones and the iPod touch we do both the blur and the
>   tinting.

The blur effect is very costly so UI can be easily GPU bound, therefore, blur effect is disabled on earlier version iPad or iPhone. As I know, there is no way to make blur effect work here.

Alternatively, You can [detect if a device support Blur effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878769/check-if-device-supports-blur) and do something accordingly.