# Transparent background is seen differently on iPad 2 vs iPad Air 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

```
VC *newView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VCUI"];
[newView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[newView view];
UIPopoverController * popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:newView];
[popoverController setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Why the transparent background is seen differently on iPad 2 vs iPad Air 2

[ipad2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzeQK.png)
[ipad air 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTtrd.png)

Comment: possible duplicate [UIToolbar not transparent on iPad2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178756/uitoolbar-not-transparent-on-ipad2)

Comment: Transparent background is invisible on iPad 2 and visible iPad Air 2 . check pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@foundry answered in this post
[UIToolbar not transparent on iPad2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178756/uitoolbar-not-transparent-on-ipad2)

> Translucency - which uses blur - is computationally expensive.
>
> If you compare the control panel or notification menu between iPad 2
>   and iPad Air, - you will see that Apple has disabled translucency on
>   the lower powered device as it can't really cope.
>
> That applies to iPad2, iPad3, iPad mini and maybe some older iPhones
>   and iPod Touches. Even higher-powered devices can give poor results if
>   you over-use these effects.
>
> If you need a completely consistent look and feel, you should resist
>   using properties that take advantage of translucency and blur effects.
>   Another option is to play around with view alpha, background colour
>   and tint to get a semi-tranparent look on devices that don't support
>   translucency.

As iPad2 is lower powered device, translucency is disabled. That's why Transparent background is invisible in your project.

If you want to know if a device support Translucency, you can have a look at this post [Check if device supports blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878769/check-if-device-supports-blur)